# Select other cells when using an ag-grid editor to simulate Excel

Tags: ag-grid

I'm looking to use ag-grid to simulate an Excel-like interface. A big piece of this is being able to be editing one cell, while scrolling around to other cells (e.g. so I can set B1 = A1). Is there a way to accomplish this with the custom editor components?

I've seen existing questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804606/ag-grid-stops-editing-cells-when-any-other-cell-on-the-grid-is-clicked-how-to-p), which make me not super hopeful - but please let me know if this can be accomplished. Thanks so much!