# AG GRID REACT - Disable RowEdit when another row is being edited

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'm new to ag grid and need some help.

I need to disable cell renderer buttons and/or row editing on all rows except the one which is being edited.

I'm using their example and all seems to work but I'm able to click on other rows and edit them despite already editing different row. So the edit and delete buttons should only be active if no other rows are being edited.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-buck-6bkhw?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A114%2C3-120%2C4

I've came across this post which suggests this cannot be done. However, this was 3 years ago so maybe it is now?

[Ag Grid stops editing cells when any other cell on the grid is clicked. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804606/ag-grid-stops-editing-cells-when-any-other-cell-on-the-grid-is-clicked-how-to-p)